# DebugDiag2 Analysis tool timeout on a dump file

Tags: windows, iis, coredump, debugdiag

I have a 6GB dump file for an IIS process that I generated and during the "Running Analysis" phase of processing I am getting a "Canceling due to timeout" message from the tool after the 60s limit.

Is there a way to increase the timeout?

Answer (score 8):

The timeout can be configured by editing the `C:\Program Files\DebugDiag\AnalysisRules\DebugDiag.AnalysisRules.dll.config` file, and updating the `GCRootTimeout` config setting:

```xml
<!-- GCRootTimeout:  maximum number of seconds to spend scanning for GC root chains -->
<add key="GCRootTimeout" value="1200"/>
```

Comment: Could you provide the location of the insert line?

Comment: In my file, this key was on line 36.  If it is not present, you should be able to add the key referenced in the answer anywhere inside of the `<configuration><appSettings>` node.

Comment: Do you know where to find this file in Azure Web Apps? Can it be edited or modified there?